# Extracting specific information from a CSV file between blocks of text

Tags: python, csv

I'm new to python and need some guidance.

I have a Text file containing output results from a multiple simulations where I need to extract specific values between each block.  See below for sample:

```html
**********************************************
SIMULATION NUMBER =     1  SEED NUMBER:      1430403561
INTERVAL    1, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL    2, NUMBER OF STORMS    1
STORM RESPONSES
  1  544.95
INTERVAL    3, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL    4, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL    5, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL    6, NUMBER OF STORMS    1
STORM RESPONSES
  1  526.68
INTERVAL    7, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL    8, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL    9, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   10, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   11, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   12, NUMBER OF STORMS    1
STORM RESPONSES
  1  518.77
INTERVAL   13, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   14, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   15, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   16, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   17, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   18, NUMBER OF STORMS    0
INTERVAL   19, NUMBER OF STORMS    1
STORM RESPONSES
  1  614.23
**********************************************
```

The information needed is between each "**********************************************" - the information between these denote individual "blocks" or simulation runs that need to be searched.

Essentially what I need is to search the blocks where "INTERVAL" values are less than or equal to 30, "NUMBER OF STORMS" are greater than 0 and the associated "STORM RESPONSES" for the "INTERVAL" above them are greater than 648.

I need a summary output table with lines stating whether the query is TRUE or FALSE for each simulation block (this particular file has 1000 simulations).

Any help would be much appreciated.  I'm sure I could figure this out in Excel, but I feel I can figure this out in Python (and can be more streamlined).

Here is what I have so far:

```html
import os
import sys

f = open('D:\log.txt')

chunks = []  #each chunk is a section of text that is what is between *** lines

tmp_text = ''
for line in f:
  if line.strip() == '******...***':
    if tmp_text != '': #I don't know if file starts with *** or not
      chunks.append(tmp_text)
      tmp_text = ''
  else:
    tmp_text += line
if tmp_text != '':
  chunks.append(tmp_text) #in case the file does not end in ****
f.close()

#chunks will be in the order that you expect them.
for chunk in chunks:
          for line in chunk :
            if "INTERVAL    " + x<=30 + ", NUMBER OF STORMS    " + x<=3 or "INTERVAL   " + x<=30 + ", NUMBER OF STORMS    " + x<=3
```

I'm getting hung up on how to extract the valueS below "STORM RESPONSES" that are less than 648.  Also, will the "if" statement I added after "for line in chunk" work?

```html
import os
import sys

f = open('D:\LBI_Easement_Issues\log.txt')

chunks = []  #each chunk is a section of text that is what is between *** lines
interval = 1
numberstorms = 1
tmp_text = ''
for line in f:
  if line.strip() == '******...***':
    if tmp_text != '': #I don't know if file starts with *** or not
      chunks.append(tmp_text)
      tmp_text = ''
  else:
    tmp_text += line
if tmp_text != '':
  chunks.append(tmp_text) #in case the file does not end in ****
f.close()

#chunks will be in the order that you expect them.
for chunk in chunks:
          for line in chunk :
            print line
            query = "True" if  "INTERVAL    " + str(interval) + ", NUMBER OF STORMS    " + str(numberstorms) or "INTERVAL   " + str(interval) + ", NUMBER OF STORMS    " + srt(numberstorms) else "False"
            print query

print "Complete"
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? You need to show us you've put in effort towards a solution. We can help you if you're stuck, be we're not going to do your work for you.

Comment: I agree with Martin.  However, if you're new to Python and programming in general, this is a common (and initially complicated) little problem. I'm sure parsing what's in between will still keep him busy!

Comment: Hi Martin, I wouldn't expect you do work for me.  Just need a little guidance - thanks for your responses and I'll post what I have so far.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you can do the processing part between the lines of asterisks, this may be helpful...

```
f = open('filename.csv')

chunks = []  #each chunk is a section of text that is what is between *** lines

tmp_text = ''
for line in f:
  if line.strip() == '******...***':
    if tmp_text != '': #I don't know if file starts with *** or not
      chunks.append(tmp_text)
      tmp_text = ''
  else:
    tmp_text += line
if tmp_text != '':
  chunks.append(tmp_text) #in case the file does not end in ****
f.close()

#chunks will be in the order that you expect them.
for chunk in chunks:
  call_your_function_to_parse_chunk_of_text_here(chunk)
```

Comment: I'm still stuck on this.  Here is what I have